# Change 'href' value of a link using PHP and DOM

Tags: php, html, dom

I would like to change all links in an HTML variable to random ones. Here is my code but something prevents links from being changed:

```
<?php
$jobTemplateDetails = '<a href="https://www2.google.com">Click!</a>
<a href="https://www3.google.com">Click!</a>';
////////////////////// CHANGE ALL LINKS
$linkDom = new DOMDocument;

@$linkDom->loadHTML($jobTemplateDetails);

$allLinks = $linkDom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($allLinks as $rawLink) {

    $longLink = $rawLink->getAttribute('href');
        $str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        $randomChar1 = $str[mt_rand(0, strlen($str)-1)];
        $randomChar2 = $str[mt_rand(0, strlen($str)-1)];
        $randomChar3 = $str[mt_rand(0, strlen($str)-1)];
        $randomChar4 = $str[mt_rand(0, strlen($str)-1)];
        $shortURL = mt_rand(1, 9).$randomChar1.mt_rand(1, 9).$randomChar2.$randomChar3.$randomChar4;
        $rawLink->setAttribute('href', $shortURL);
}
echo $jobTemplateDetails;
```

Comment: you know, that when you `echo $jobTemplateDetails;` you only show the very first input, but not what you might have changed with the code afterwards?

Comment: You should use `echo $allLinks->saveHTML()` to show chages

Comment: @Jeff Thank you! How can I save the changes to the variable then?

Comment: @Mohammad dear Mohammad, it produces an error like this: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::saveHTML()`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php

Comment: @RezaKazemifar Use `$linkDom` instead of `$allLinks`. I wrote it wrong

Comment: at the end do `echo $linkDom->saveHTML();` instead of `echo $jobTemplateDetails;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `echo $jobTemplateDetails;` you only show the very first input string, not the DomDocument you manipulate.
Change that to

```
echo $linkDom->saveHTML();

///OUTPUT:
<a href="7y2rpn">Click!</a>
<a href="3b5qtr">Click!</a>
```

a fiddle: https://3v4l.org/KuCic
and [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)